# Automatically change the name of column everywhere with the renaming the name of column

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I need to change my column name in mysql and I want to automatically update all triggers, procedures, functions where that name is used to new name. How can I do this?

I tried this syntax but it doesn't effect to my funcs, proc etc.

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE col1 col2 double;
```

Comment: You can't......

Comment: best is to make a sql export and change it with a text editor or other tools like awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of changing a column name and automatically updating all referenced objects.

Your best option is to query objects using `information_schema` tables and change them.

For example, to query stored procedures and user defined functions that its definition has reference to `col1`:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_definition LIKE '%col1%'
```

[information_schema reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html)